# Open source tools for automation of Java GUI application testing

Tags: automated-testing, java, java-gui, testing-framework

The testing tools (or tools that could be used in testing purposes) for testing Java GUI application I know are:

- **[Jemmy](http://wiki.netbeans.org/Jemmy)** - [jemmy](/questions/tagged/jemmy) library contains methods to reproduce all user actions which can be performed on Swing/AWT components (i.e. button pushing, text typing, tree node expanding, ...). Could be used with any Java IDE (Eclipse, NetBeans) & automated test framework ([JUnit](http://junit.org/), [TestNG](http://testng.org/doc/index.html)) that gives you much freedom (e.g. analyze JVM memory usage). 
  **N.B.:** *looks like Jemmy does NOT support Java web-start applications* (with downloading of .jnlp file) as it is mentioned in posts [testing Java web-start app using Jemmy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24630117/testing-java-web-start-application-using-jemmy) & [how to automate a swing java web-start app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23681949/how-to-automate-a-swing-java-web-start-application-which-runs-clicking-a-link-in), but still it is possible to test this kind of apps with great flexibility so I use this tool now. Testing app does not download & start `.jnlp` file, but starting script (vbscript) downloads `.jar` files of AUT (by the same link `.jnlp` file is downloaded) and testing app uses these files of a new AUT build.
- **[Jubula](http://www.eclipse.org/jubula/)** - [jubula](/questions/tagged/jubula) is an Eclipse based automated functional GUI testing framework for Java and HTML. Uses blocks as association with actions performed during test, developer does not write code just assembling test actions from available building blocks.
- **[Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/)** - [sikuli](/questions/tagged/sikuli) suits for testing any application (image recognition based) that does not require working with precise text data. The tool has it's limitations ([check here](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/994/under-what-circumstances-is-sikuli-better-for-test-automation-than-selenium-or-w)), using it to test RDP stuff.
- **[Abbot framework](http://abbot.sourceforge.net/doc/overview.shtml)** - for automated testing of Java GUI components and programs (did not study yet...)

What else can you suggest? Open source and for Java GUI testing.

Comment: Have you tried Selenium Webdriver?

Comment: @TESTasy, tried, but unfortunately it works only with web-applications. Selenium WEBdriver is not for GUI tests

Comment: I typically use [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) scripts to simulate keyboard presses and mouse movement. It's a bit hacky, but it gets the job done. It also works for automating applications if you don't have access to the source code.

Answer (score 9):

If the Java GUI application is based on Swing, [AssertJ Swing](https://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-swing.html) is probably one of the best open source libraries. It's a fork of [FEST](https://code.google.com/archive/p/fest/) and has several advantages:

> - [Simulation of user interaction](https://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-swing-input.html) with a GUI (e.g. drag 'n drop)
> - Reliable [GUI component lookup](https://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-swing-lookup.html) (by type, by name or custom search criteria)
> - Support for all Swing components included in the JDK
> - Compact and powerful API for creation and maintenance of functional GUI tests
> - Supports [Applet testing](https://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-swing-launch.html#applets)
> - Ability to embed [screenshots of failed GUI tests](https://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-swing-troubleshooting-screenshots.html) in HTML test reports
> - Can be used with either [TestNG](http://testng.org/) or [JUnit](http://junit.org/)
> - Supports [testing violations](https://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-swing-edt.html#testing-violations) of Swing's threading rules
> - Can be used with [JIDE Software](http://www.jidesoft.com/) (since 1.1.0)

Moreover, it's actively maintained, offers a comprehensive documentation, supports Java 8, and [AssertJ](https://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/index.html) itself has some neat assertions.

Comment: Can AssertJ Swing be used to automate third party java web applets without having access to the source code? I couldn't find any way to gain access to an existing window from the documentation.

Answer (score 4):

I know about several open source tools hosted on GitHub but didn't try them yet. Just created a list for future learning. Any additions and comments are welcome.

- [TestFX](https://github.com/TestFX/TestFX) - 213*
- [Automation](https://github.com/renatoathaydes/Automaton) (Groovy & Java) - 48*
- [swinger](https://github.com/demetriusnunes/swinger) (JRuby, Cucumber-based) - 47*
- [Marathon](https://github.com/jalian-systems/Marathon) - 31*
- [Window Tester](https://github.com/google/windowtester) - 5*

This list might be updated in the future. I'm maintaining it [at the pywinauto project wiki page](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/wiki/Automation-for-many-platforms-(links)) (pywinauto doesn't support Java at all, but Java GUI experts are very welcome).

Comment: Can these be used for third party Java Applets we don't have the source code for?

Comment: Probably yes. You can also check these applets with Inspect.exe tool which is [available here](https://github.com/blackrosezy/gui-inspect-tool). Some Java apps can be automated by pywinauto, but your chances are ~50% and it's Windows only. Didn't try other tools, just aware of them. :)

Comment: So you wouldn't be able to demonstrate the usage for these tools?

Answer (score 1):

[Swing Testing Toolkit](http://otksoftware.com/swing-testing-toolkit/) (uses a semi-automatic test case generation approach aimed at reducing testing instructions to the bare minimum while ensuring that they are as relevant as possible).
It is not a universal GUI testing framework. It focuses on a single library (Swing) to guarantee its level of quality.

Answer (score 1):

- [Marathon](https://github.com/jalian-systems/marathonv5) is an OSS Test Automation Tool which has main features to [record](https://marathontesting.com/marathonite/automated-test-recorder/), [playback](https://marathontesting.com/marathonite/test-runner/) the events performed on AUT.It allows to [debug](https://marathontesting.com/marathonite/test-script-debugger/) the test scripts recorded. The test scripts are created in **Ruby** (Older version supports **Python** also).
  It also has features like [Object Mapping](https://marathontesting.com/marathonite/object-map-editor/) , Allure Report Generation,Test Organisation(Features and Stories), Reusable Modules in test scripts.
- Commercial version [MarathonITE](https://marathontesting.com) has much more features like [Centralised Object-Map repository](https://marathontesting.com/marathonite/object-map-server/), [Data-Driven Testing](https://marathontesting.com/marathonite/data-driven-tests/) and ...
- It has **Java agent** which launches application and creates a **Java Server** on which you can use **Selenium** **RemoteWebDriver** to make connection to it and perform calls.
- **Java Driver** which allows you to  create **Java Profile** to launch application in different launcher models

  - Java Command Line
  - Applet Launcher
  - Command Line Launcher(.bat/.sh)
  - WebStart Launcher

Note: I'm also a contributor to Marathon.

Comment: Please disclose your affiliation with Marathon, since it appears that you are listed as one of the contributors to the source code. You can find more information about handling references to affiliated sites here: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/help/promotion In general it's better to say something than to risk people thinking you are spamming.

Comment: @KatePaulk Thanks for pointing out . This is the first time I'm answering in stack overflow. I'm editing the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Testmate to automate Java swing application
https://youtu.be/BQQdJ0V23GM