# Automation Testing for Installer created using IzPack

Tags: automated-testing

I want to automate the GUI installation process on Windows and Linux.

Suggest me good tools which can I use for both OS.

Answer (score 1):

Java is a good tool for that. As per [this wiki page](https://izpack.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/IZPACK/pages/42663940/Installation+Modes), IzPack supports several installation modes:

> - Interactive Installations Providing a Swing GUI
> - Interactive Installations Providing in a Text Console
> - Unattended Installations Using Records of Previous Sessions
> - Unattended Installations Using Properties
> - Mixed Installation Mode Using Variable Defaults

Which means you can either take GUI or CLI or environment under control to generate input signals.

- For GUI (since it's a Swing) you might be interested in this post: [Open source tools for automation of Java GUI application testing](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/18554/open-source-tools-for-automation-of-java-gui-application-testing)
- Interaction with CLI is quite straightforward task and does not require any libraries except of the ones packaged with standard JDK bundle. This [official Oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/cl.html) will give you a good starting point.
- Other types of installation does not require any frameworks either.

**Note**, that for different platforms IzPack might provide some native features that might require non-trivial approaches (like read values from [System Registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62289/read-write-to-windows-registry-using-java))

Comment: can you also suggest a good tool among GUI tools which works on both OS?